# WPF - EllipseGeometry animation in C# using a Storyboard

Tags: c#, wpf, storyboard, scaletransform, wpf-animation

I need to scale an EllipseGeometry in C# with ScaleTransform, but it doesn't works.
Here's the code:

XAML:

```
<Image x:Name="rock" Stretch="None">
    <Image.Clip>
        <EllipseGeometry x:Name="rockClip" RadiusX="100" RadiusY="100" Center="200,150">
            <EllipseGeometry.Transform>
                    <ScaleTransform/>
            </EllipseGeometry.Transform>
        </EllipseGeometry>
    </Image.Clip>
</Image>
```

C#:

```
DoubleAnimation scaleX = new DoubleAnimation();
scaleX.BeginTime = TimeSpan.FromMilliseconds(fromMills);
scaleX.Duration = new Duration(TimeSpan.FromMilliseconds(2000));
scaleX.From = 0.0;
scaleX.To = 1.0;
scaleX.SetValue(Storyboard.TargetProperty, rockClip);
scaleX.SetValue(Storyboard.TargetPropertyProperty, new PropertyPath("(EllipseGeometry.Transform).(ScaleTransform.ScaleX)"));

DoubleAnimation scaleY = new DoubleAnimation();
scaleY.BeginTime = TimeSpan.FromMilliseconds(fromMills);
scaleY.Duration = new Duration(TimeSpan.FromMilliseconds(2000));
scaleY.From = 0.0;
scaleY.To = 1.0;
scaleY.SetValue(Storyboard.TargetProperty, rockClip);
scaleY.SetValue(Storyboard.TargetPropertyProperty, new PropertyPath("(EllipseGeometry.Transform).(ScaleTransform.ScaleY)"));

Storyboard storyboard = new Storyboard();
storyboard.Children.Add(scaleX);
storyboard.Children.Add(scaleY);
storyboard.Completed += storyboard_Completed;
animation.Begin();
```

The storyboard_Completed event is triggered but there is no animation on the EllipseGeometry.

Where is the problem?

I can animate the EllipseGeometry only in this way:

```
DoubleAnimation scale = new DoubleAnimation();
scale.From = 0;
scale.To = 40;
scale.Duration = new Duration(TimeSpan.FromMilliseconds(5000));
rockClip.BeginAnimation(EllipseGeometry.RadiusXProperty, scale);
rockClip.BeginAnimation(EllipseGeometry.RadiusYProperty, scale);
```

I need to put this DoubleAnimation in a Storyboard, but I don't know how.

Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It works if you use the Image control (instead of the Geometry) as target element:

```
var scaleX = new DoubleAnimation();
scaleX.BeginTime = TimeSpan.FromMilliseconds(fromMills);
scaleX.Duration = TimeSpan.FromSeconds(2);
scaleX.From = 0.0;
scaleX.To = 1.0;
Storyboard.SetTarget(scaleX, rock);
Storyboard.SetTargetProperty(scaleX, new PropertyPath("Clip.Transform.ScaleX"));

var scaleY = new DoubleAnimation();
scaleY.BeginTime = TimeSpan.FromMilliseconds(fromMills);
scaleY.Duration = TimeSpan.FromSeconds(2);
scaleY.From = 0.0;
scaleY.To = 1.0;
Storyboard.SetTarget(scaleY, rock);
Storyboard.SetTargetProperty(scaleY, new PropertyPath("Clip.Transform.ScaleY"));

var storyboard = new Storyboard();
storyboard.Children.Add(scaleX);
storyboard.Children.Add(scaleY);
storyboard.Begin();
```

---

However, the most simply way may be to name the ScaleTransform

```
<EllipseGeometry.Transform>
    <ScaleTransform x:Name="scale"/>
</EllipseGeometry.Transform>
```

and run the animations like this:

```
var scaleAnimation = new DoubleAnimation
{
    BeginTime = TimeSpan.FromMilliseconds(fromMills),
    Duration = TimeSpan.FromSeconds(2),
    From = 0.0,
    To = 1.0
};

scale.BeginAnimation(ScaleTransform.ScaleXProperty, scaleAnimation);
scale.BeginAnimation(ScaleTransform.ScaleYProperty, scaleAnimation);
```

---

EDIT: In order to animate the `RadiusX` and `RadiusY` properties by means of a Storyboard, you could write this:

```
var radiusXAnimation = new DoubleAnimation();
radiusXAnimation.BeginTime = TimeSpan.FromMilliseconds(fromMills);
radiusXAnimation.Duration = TimeSpan.FromSeconds(2);
radiusXAnimation.From = 0;
radiusXAnimation.To = 100;
Storyboard.SetTarget(radiusXAnimation, rock);
Storyboard.SetTargetProperty(radiusXAnimation, new PropertyPath("Clip.RadiusX"));

var radiusYAnimation = new DoubleAnimation();
radiusYAnimation.BeginTime = TimeSpan.FromMilliseconds(fromMills);
radiusYAnimation.Duration = TimeSpan.FromSeconds(2);
radiusYAnimation.From = 0;
radiusYAnimation.To = 100;
Storyboard.SetTarget(radiusYAnimation, rock);
Storyboard.SetTargetProperty(radiusYAnimation, new PropertyPath("Clip.RadiusY"));

var storyboard = new Storyboard();
storyboard.Children.Add(radiusXAnimation);
storyboard.Children.Add(radiusYAnimation);
storyboard.Begin();
```

Comment: Thanks Clemens, it works using the image control as target.
How can I change the render transform origin? I tried with `<Image x:Name="rock" Stretch="None" RenderTransformOrigin="0.5, 0.5">` but it doesn't works.
So I changed the CenterX/Y `<ScaleTransform CenterX="200" CenterY="150"/>`, in this way the animation ends correctly (in the middle of the 400x300 image) but starts in the top left of the image (and not in the middle).
How can I change the render transform origin (possibly using 0..1 values)? Thanks for your help.

Comment: It's not clear what exactly you want to achieve. First you don't animate a RenderTransform, but the Transform of a Clip geometry. If you want to keep the Clip geometry's Center, you should not animate the geometry's Transform, but instead animate its RadiusX and RadiusY (as you already did).

Comment: Yes, I want to keep clip geometry's center. With `rockClip.BeginAnimation(EllipseGeometry.RadiusXProperty, scale)` it works fine but I don't know how to put this animation inside a Storyboard. How can I achieve this? Thanks!

Comment: I put the ScaleTransform in a TransformGroup: `<EllipseGeometry.Transform><TransformGroup><ScaleTransform CenterX="200" CenterY="150"/></TransformGroup></EllipseGeometry.Transform>` but I don't know how to set the target property. I tried this: `Storyboard.SetTargetProperty(scaleX, new PropertyPath("(Clip.Transform).(TransformGroup.Children)[0].(ScaleTransform.ScaleY)"))` but it doesn't works. Where is the problem?

Comment: Is it possible to animate the Clip opacity? I tried with `Storyboard.SetTarget(fade, target); Storyboard.SetTargetProperty(fade, new PropertyPath("Clip.Opacity"));` (where fade is the DoubleAnimation and target is the image) but it doesn't works.

Comment: Clip is a Geometry, which has no Opacity property. Please stop asking questions in comments. Ask another regular question on StackOverflow.